# JavaScript filter out one element

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

I want to remove one element by id from the animals list.

```
this.setState((state) => ({
  animals: state.animals.filter(animal => animal.id !== id),
}));
```

The collection is in random order. Is there better way to filter out one element?

Comment: That's a great way ;)

Comment: Could not be better.

Comment: It’s good enough. I cannot think of better way.

Comment: You could implement an exit condition so it would not have to iterate over all items if you only need to remove one

Comment: I was thinking about exit condition. I think I would need to use `find` in such a case. Given the random order, on average, I think the time complexity goes down from `T(n)` to `T(n/2)`. Is it worth it?

Comment: Obviously you could store the animals in a Map keyed off ID and then simply delete the ID from the Map in O(1). But it would have potential impact on the remainder of your code, if your code assumes that animals is actually an array rather than an iterable collection.

Comment: Do some benchmarking after you know how large your dataset can get and then decide if there's need for optimisation.

Comment: Better how? Faster? Less code? [More jQuery](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/194720)?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I think code transparency is the primary goal for me.

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking -- define "better", define "code transparency". This method filters the array for items that don't have a matching id. You could use findIndex and get the item's index, then delete it from the array, then filter(a => a) the array... is that more transparent? It certainly would take more lines. Who's the audience?